# Как использовать @DisallowConcurrentExecution для последовательного выполнения работ?

Tags: java, quartz

У меня есть планировщик:

```
public class Main {
    private static Scheduler sched;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.INFO);
        try {
            SchedulerFactory schedFact = new org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties");
            sched = schedFact.getScheduler();
            sched.start();
            JobDetail jobDetail;
            CronTrigger trigger;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                jobDetail = newJob(ReportJob.class)
                        .withIdentity("name" + i, "gr")
                        .build();
                jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("name", "job " + i);
                trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("trigger" + i, "gr")
                        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 40 14 * * ?")
                        .build();

                sched.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception while scheduling job" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

и сама работа:

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class ReportJob implements Job {

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        String name = (String) context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get("name");
        System.out.println(name + "| job for report started");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(name + "| job for report ended");
    }
}
```

Я использую `quartz-2.2.3` и аннотацию `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` для последовательного выполнения работ, однако, тем не менее, работы выполняются параллельно:

> job 0| job for report started
>
> job 1| job for report started
>
> job 2| job for report started
>
> job 0| job for report ended
>
> job 1| job for report ended
>
> job 2| job for report ended

Я же хочу, чтобы работы выполнялись следующим образом:

> job 0| job for report started
>
> job 0| job for report ended
>
> job 1| job for report started
>
> job 1| job for report ended
>
> job 2| job for report started
>
> job 2| job for report ended

Насколько я понимаю, мне нужно прописать в файле `quartz.properties` свойство

```
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=1
```

и добавить какую-то из [`Misfire Instructions`](http://javamoody.blogspot.com.by/2015/05/running-quartz-job-with.html). Однако ни одна из тех, которые возможны для моего триггера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не даёт нужного результата. Что ещё нужно использовать, кроме `@DisallowConcurrentExecution`, для последовательного выполнения работ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я поняла свою ошибку: `@DisallowConcurrentExecution` предотвращает выполнение нескольких экземпляров задания с тем же ключом (`JobKey`) одновременно. В то время как я использовала задания с разными ключами.